# App crash on preview for very large post body

Tags: bug, ios-app

I just paste ~200 kB of text to the body of a new question in the iOS app and tap on the yellow header to preview.

> [image: Preview button]

This leads to crash the app. In some cases the app crashed after cutting the selected text from the body.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.1.2 (Build 15B202)